# Spring framework and Webmethod: is it possible to lodge the host from which a web request is originated?

Tags: spring, webmethod

I am using spring framework 2.5.6.

Says I have this piece of code:

```
@WebMethod(operationName='hello')
@WebResult(name='result')
public List<Result> getResult(@WebParam(name='myname') Request request)
...
```

How can I work out the ip or host from which the request is sent to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
            MessageContext msgCtxt = wsContext.getMessageContext();
            ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest) msgCtxt.get("javax.xml.ws.servlet.request");
            LOG.info("IP is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
```

wsContext is an private variable of `WebServiceContext`